# how to add inline css to rails link_to helper

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

am on rails 5 and my categories have images. i want to use those images as backround images but when i set in the styling the url do not change

```
<div class="grid-category">
    <% @servicescategories.each do |category| %>

    <%= link_to servicecategories_path(slug: category.slug ), :style=>'background-image: asset-data-url("category.category_image");',  class: "category-item" do %>



        <h3> <%= category.name %></h3>


        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interpolate the value of `category.category_image`

```
<%= link_to servicecategories_path(slug: category.slug ),  
            class: "category-item" do %>

  <div style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path('category.category_image') %>)">
    <h3> <%= category.name %></h3>
  </div> 

<% end %>
```

Comment: it returns it like `<a style="background-image: url(/category.category_image)" class="category-item" href="/services/facial">`

Comment: @geniuskidkanyi what output do you expect

Comment: i expect to ouput the url of the image to be use as background image

Comment: well I tried the property is applied there but image is not coming

Comment: the return code is ` "background-image: url(/category.category_image)" ` which doesnt turn catefory / -image into url

Comment: i tried this one background-image is not working with link

but is working on a div

Comment: how would i do it with div?

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have the incorrect syntax to use the rails interpolation inside the style attribute, 
Try this,

```
 <%= link_to servicecategories_path(slug: category.slug ),
 :style=>"background-image: <%= asset-data-url(category.category_image) %>",
   class: "category-item" do %>
```

Comment: it doesnt work. it return it like this `  <a style="background-image: #{asset-data-url(&quot;category.category_image&quot;);}" class="category-item" href="/services/skincare"> `

Comment: chnaged the code in the answer please check with that,

`<%= link_to servicecategories_path(slug: category.slug ),
 :style=>"background-image: <%= asset-data-url(category.category_image) %>",
   class: "category-item" do %>`

Comment: this now returns ` unknown regexp options - dv  `

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
<%= link_to servicecategories_path(slug: category.slug ),  
            class: "category-item" do %>

  <div style="background-image: <%= asset_path('category.category_image') %>">
    <h3> <%= category.name %></h3>
  </div> 

<% end %>
```